# Why is the float * int multiplication faster than int * float in CPython?

Tags: python, multiplication, cpython

Basically, the expression `0.4 * a` is consistently, and surprisingly, significantly faster than `a * 0.4`. `a` being an integer. And I have no idea why.

I speculated that it is a case of a `LOAD_CONST LOAD_FAST` bytecode pair being "more specialized" than the `LOAD_FAST LOAD_CONST` and I would be entirely satisfied with this explanation, except that this quirk seems to apply only to multiplications where types of multiplied variables differ. (By the way, I can no longer find the link to this "bytecode instruction pair popularity ranking" I once found on github, does anyone have a link?)

Anyway, here are the micro benchmarks:

```bash
$ python3.10 -m pyperf timeit -s"a = 9" "a * 0.4"
Mean +- std dev: 34.2 ns +- 0.2 ns
```

```bash
$ python3.10 -m pyperf timeit -s"a = 9" "0.4 * a"
Mean +- std dev: 30.8 ns +- 0.1 ns
```

```bash
$ python3.10 -m pyperf timeit -s"a = 0.4" "a * 9"
Mean +- std dev: 30.3 ns +- 0.3 ns
```

```bash
$ python3.10 -m pyperf timeit -s"a = 0.4" "9 * a"
Mean +- std dev: 33.6 ns +- 0.3 ns
```

As you can see - in the runs where the float comes first (2nd and 3rd) - it is faster.
So my question is where does this behavior come from? I'm 90% sure that it is an implementation detail of CPython, but I'm not that familiar with low level instructions to state that for sure.

Comment: My guess: `float.__add__` immediately converts the integer to a `float`, where as `int.__add__` raises `NotImplemented`, forcing `float.__radd__` to be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's CPython's implementation of the `BINARY_MULTIPLY` opcode. It has no idea what the types are at compile-time, so everything has to be figured out at run-time. Regardless of what `a` and `b` may be, `BINARY_MULTIPLY` ends up inoking `a.__mul__(b)`.

When `a` is of int type `int.__mul__(a, b)` has no idea what to do unless `b` is also of int type. It returns `Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED` (an internal C constant). This is in `longobject.c`'s `CHECK_BINOP` macro. The interpreter sess that, and effectively says "OK, `a.__mul__` has no idea what to do, so let's give `b.__rmul__` a shot at it". None of that is free - it all takes time.

`float.__mul__(b, a)` (same as `float.__rmul__`) does know what to do with an int (converts it to float first), so that succeeds.

But when `a` is of float type to begin with, we go to `float.__mul__` first, and that's the end of it. No time burned figuring out that the int type doesn't know what to do.

The actual code is quite a bit more involved than the above pretends, but that's the gist of it.